# TFS Build and Alerts for Success / Failure

Tags: tfs, build

I'm using TFS 2008 and the TFS Build Service. I am able to perform builds, but I'm annoyed about receiving alerts for successful builds. I only want to receive a notification when a build does NOT succeed. Not sure why I can't find this setting, but maybe it is not offered. Does anybody know if this is possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to configure this is to install the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) on your machine.  This will add a more powerful alerts editor into Visual Studio.  You can then edit the email alert that will already exist for you, or create another one, but filter it so that you will only get notified when the build status is failed.

Answer (score 1):

Jason Prickett has a blog post on [How to Filter the Build Completion Event](http://blogs.msdn.com/jpricket/archive/2006/09/05/how-to-filter-the-build-completion-event.aspx) that you should find helpful. His article targeted TFS 2005, but it should be equally applicable to TFS 2008. It's a more involved process than it ought to be, but it is possible.